# Invisible View in ReactJS

Tags: android, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make hidden `view` as like android has. This occupies the space but it doesn't show to the user.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/hiddenView"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

What is the way to do this in `ReactJS` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `visibility` set to `hidden` in the style of your html element in your react component. See example below.

```js
function InvisibleDiv() {
  return <div style={{width: '50', height:'50', backgroundColor: 'red',visibility: 'hidden'}}></div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<InvisibleDiv />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I want to place div tag between `TextField` and `FlatButton`. It is getting placed below `TextField` in new line. https://pastebin.com/Vywt6gJm here it is http://imgur.com/a/MaTHA

Comment: That is because your textfield and flatbutton has style set to 48%. the 4% remaining space is not enough to contain the div that may take more space, so it will go to the new line. Either change the width in TextField and FlatButton or in the div that you've created.

Comment: I have this  `<div
              style={{
                width: "4%",
                height: "50",
                backgroundColor: "red"
              }}
            />
` as 48% is for `TextView` and `FlatButton` and remaining 4% is for div. It is still in new line

Comment: is there any margin on the Flatbutton and TextView? or perhaps padding on the parent element of Flatbutton? try giving the div a 2% width. If you want to make them display side by side, add the style property `float: 'left'` to all of the elements (e.g div, FlatButton, TextView)

Comment: By adding `float: left` worked for me. Do you have docs of it ? I will read it Ah I found in https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: Short docs: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp, Long docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats,

Answer (score 2):

In CSS you can achieve this by setting the `visibility: hidden` property. Whereas to completely hide the space occupied by it as well, you should use `display: none`.